# determining logic error that causes a misprint

Tags: java, debugging

So, I am pretty new to java and I wanted to try my hand at debugging in command line, namely using jdb on a code that has a couple errors. I was tinkering with this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

class LetterHome{

   static final int MAX_CODE = 5;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
      String phrase;
      int sentenceCode, modifierCode;

      System.out.println("Dear Mom and Dad:\n");


      while( in.hasNext() ){

         sentenceCode = in.nextInt();
         modifierCode = in.nextInt();


         if( (sentenceCode < 1) || (sentenceCode >= MAX_CODE) ) {
            System.out.println(sentenceCode + " is not a valid sentence code");
            continue;
         }


         if( sentenceCode == 1 ){
            if( modifierCode == 1 ){
               phrase = "great";
            }else if( modifierCode == 2 ){
               phrase = "ok";
            }else{
               phrase = "ERROR";
            }
            System.out.println("My classes are going " + phrase + ".");

         }else if( sentenceCode == 2 ){
            phrase = weatherModifier(modifierCode);
            System.out.println("The weather here has been " + phrase + ".");

         }else if( sentenceCode == 3 ){
            if( modifierCode == 1 ){
               phrase = "after the quarter ends";
            }else if( modifierCode == 2 ){
               phrase = "in a few weeks";
            }else if( modifierCode == 3 ){
               phrase = "next weekend";
            }else{
               phrase = "ERROR";
            }
            System.out.println("I plan to come home for a visit " + phrase + ".");

         }else if( sentenceCode == 4 ){
            System.out.println("Do you think you could send me $" + modifierCode + "?");
            System.out.println("I have to buy another book for one of my classes.");

         }else if( sentenceCode == 5 ){
            if( modifierCode == 1 ){
               phrase = "cookies";
            }else if( modifierCode == 2 ){
               phrase = "stuff";
            }else; if( modifierCode == 3 ){
               phrase = "money";
            }else{
               phrase = "ERROR";
            }
            System.out.println("Thanks for the " + phrase + " you sent.");
         }
      }
   }


   static String weatherModifier(int m) {
      String word=null;


      if(m == 1)
         word = "great";
      if(m == 2)
         word = "foggy";
      if(m == 3)
         word = "hot";
      if(m == 4)
         word = "cold";
      if(m == 5)
         word = "variable";
      if( m<1 && m>5)
         word = "ERROR";

      return word;
   }

}
```

And I've already found a ";" that was out of place. I know that something is off with the values assigned to the terms in the end (I think), because when I compile the program, I get this output:

```
Dear Mom and Dad:
//
//             5 is not a valid sentence code
//             My classes are going great.
//             The weather here has been foggy.
//             I plan to come home for a visit in a few weeks.
```

Instead of classes going "great", I get "foggy", which I noticed when I ran jdb. I ran the code with this data file:

```
5 2
1 1
2 1
3 2
```

The code itself prints a template with possible options outlined in the data file, which you may have already noticed. Here's the full list of possibilities:

```
//             1. My classes are going _____.
//                  1. great
//                  2. ok
//             2. The weather here has been _____.
//                  1. great
//                  2. foggy
//                  3. hot
//                  4. cold
//                  5. variable
//             3. I plan to come home for a visit _____.
//                  1. after the quarter ends
//                  2. in a few weeks
//                  3. next weekend
//             4. Do you think you could send me $_____?
//                I have to buy another book for one of my classes.
//             5. Thanks for the _____ you sent.
//                  1. cookies
//                  2. stuff
//                  3. money
```

However, I'm not sure what's off about the logic in the code. Any tips? Please let me know if I need to make some clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of this use debug mode in your IDE

Answer (score 0):

You added an extra `;`at the end of `if (m==2);` in your `weatherModifier` function. Remove it!

Comment: oh sorry - In my question I mentioned that I already removed that. I'll update the post. There's another issue, I think having to do with the values I am using... but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, actually:

It was in " if( (sentenceCode < 1) || (sentenceCode >= MAX_CODE) )"

I had to change ">=" to ">"